# How to I increase the time that the infotainment remains on before shutting off in Accessories mode on a 2016 Mazda cx5?

Tags: mazda, infotainment

I have a 2016 Mazda CX-5 GT. In the CX-5, you press the start button once without the foot on the brake in order to start accessories.  But after 15 or 20 minutes, the infotainment shuts off.  I wasn't able to tell if it was all accessories or just infotainment.

I assume this is by design in order to conserve battery.  But I wish to keep the radio on since we were at a drive-in movie theater where the sound plays over an FM radio station.  I had to get up (we sit outside the vehicle with the back hatch open) 4 or 5 times in order to turn the radio back on.  Not a huge deal, but if I can re-configure, I would.

Is the amount of time configurable and if so, how do I change it?